# Dynamic PDF generation

Tags: php, html, css, pdf

this is what i'm trying to do. I have a Student Result Application in
 which i'll like to print out a pdf format of a specially designed
 Result's Sheet..

http://www.4shared.com/photo/yg8vCjYe/results_layout.html

My question is that is it possible to send all the html, css and php
 variables from the final result sheet to the pdf engine, or just
 design a new page result_printout.php page and implement the
 pdf engine on that page.
I'll be happy your honest opinions

thanks for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

honestly, i haven't done this before,
but i think this should help:
http://www.rustyparts.com/pdf.php

Answer (score 0):

Since you allready have the HTML I would suggest to use [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/). There also some wrappers for PHP. It's allways a bit tricky to get it all work in the right way, especially with pagebreaks.

But I find it usually more easy to use then all the other PHP PDF creation classes/libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I have only worked with MPDF and you can pretty much send all the html, css and php variables to the pdf enginge and tell the engine to either force a download or send it to the browser where the user can either save the file or print or just view it. You can also email the generated pdf.

You can read the documentation here: http://mpdf1.com/manual/